# Exception in ActiveMQ log in Java web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic

Though I didn't get any error or problem in my system, Why I am getting this Exception in log.
I tried to figure out the problem from http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/activemq/thread/Scheduler.java.html, I didn't get anything useful.Please help me.

I am using java.util.Timer to schedule set of Tasks.

My Web Application Details.

```
Web Server : Tomcat 5.5
JMS queue
ActiveMQ : 5
```

Exception trace :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ecnet.core.util.ReloadableResourceBundle.checkAll(ReloadableResourceBundle.java:319)
    at ecnet.core.util.ReloadableResourceBundle$1.run(ReloadableResourceBundle.java:227)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "InactivityMonitor WriteCheck" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.writeCheck(InactivityMonitor.java:147)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor$2.run(InactivityMonitor.java:113)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.SchedulerTimerTask.run(SchedulerTimerTask.java:33)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
perrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr    RED DRAGON PRIMARY
```

Comment: You need to include the exception stack trace otherwise there's pretty much no way to know what might have happened.

Comment: How is the first exception ("`TimerTask`") related to the two other ones, and what type of exception is the first one?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup sorry for the "typo".I edited the question.